# Searching MySQL for part of an array

Tags: mysql, pdo

Im trying to take an array of titles from the column 'list' and then get details for every title on said list.

```
//Get list
$r=$link->prepare('SELECT list FROM lists WHERE user=? LIMIT 1');
$r->bindValue(1,$user,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$r->execute();
$list=$r->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//See how many titles the list has  
$list_length=count($list);

//Get details for every title   
for($i=0;$i<$list_length;$i++)
{
    $r2=$link->prepare('SELECT * FROM details WHERE title=?');
    $r2->bindValue(1,$list[$i],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $r2->execute();
    $details=$r2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
return json_encode($details);
```

As it is I get echoed just `[]`.

I also get `Notice: Array to string conversion in` `$r2->bindValue(1,$list[$i],PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: I guess you want to pass the list title to your where query? $r2->bindValue(1,$list[$i]['title'],PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: @Stromgren The list has no title, but is an array comprised of titles, as in {John, Mary, George, etc.}. I need to query the database for each of the titles.

Comment: @Stromgren Oh sorry I misunderstood you! XD You were right, that takes care of the problem.

Comment: hey you do know that `LIMIT 1` will return just one row? this combined to naming only one field to be selected will pretty much ensure to ever only receive one field from your query... `count($list)` with the return of a `fetchAll()` on a `LIMIT 1` query will always be 1.

Comment: I only do need one field as it is a list of titles. I may have expressed myself badly.

Comment: you shouldn't store multiple lists in the same field in the first place.

Comment: Why do people use databases without reading up on the basics and  understanding what the do ?

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to learn to **read your code**, instead of asking others to do it for you.

   ```
   SELECT list FROM lists WHERE user=? LIMIT 1
   ```

   Look at this query. Does it looks like one that can return an **array** of rows?
2. Learn SQL. And JOINS particularly

And here goes the code

```
$sql = 'SELECT details.*  FROM lists JOIN details on title=list WHERE user=?';
$stm = $link->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute([$user]);
json_encode($stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Just FOUR lines

Comment: Maybe you should start to learn to read other peoples code, as this is not what I am asking at all.

Comment: That's what written in your code exactly. So, someone indeed need to learn ;)